# Web GUI for Skype? Or portable Skype?

Tags: windows, skype, instant-messaging

I need to use Skype without installing it.

Are there any choices for doing this, such as a web GUI? Or are there any non-trojaned portable versions? I'm looking for anything that will work on Windows XP or Windows 7.

Comment: http://gigaom.com/2011/06/28/skype-xmpp-support/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Imo.im](https://imo.im/) is a website that lets you chat with your friends on Skype online.

You can also download a portable version of Skype from [here](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/skype_portable).

Comment: :O good to know, ty!